# Trying to create a menu in java to calculate and display information about a circle

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to java and I've been working through some questions and have been mostly okay but I've had a lot of trouble with this question which asks me to create a menu to find out and display various information about a circle. My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Circle2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final double pi = 3.1416;
        Scanner values = new Scanner(System.in);
        char response;
        double area, perimeter, radius; 

        do // put code in loop
        {
            // offer menu of options

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("*** CIRCLE MENU ***"); // create a blank line
            System.out.println("[1] Set radius");
            System.out.println("[2] Display radius");
            System.out.println("[3] Display area");
            System.out.println("[4] Display perimeter");
            System.out.println("[5] Quit");
            System.out.println("Enter choice [1,2,3,4,5}: ");
            response = values.next().charAt(0); // get response
            System.out.println(); // create a blank line

            switch(response) // process response
            {
                case '1': System.out.println("Enter a value for the radius: ");
                          radius = values.nextDouble();
                            while(radius < 0)
                            {
                            System.out.println("Please enter a non-negative radius: ");
                            radius = values.nextDouble(); 
                            }
                          break;
                case '2': System.out.println("The radius is " + radius);
                          break;
                case '3': System.out.println("The area is " +  (pi * radius * radius));
                          break;
                case '4': System.out.println("The perimeter is " + (2 * pi * radius));
                          break;
                case '5': System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                          break;
                default:  System.out.println("Options 1-5 only!");
            }

        } while (response != '5'); // test for Quit option  
    }   
}
```

The errors I keep getting are in the switch case, I've tried putting the first case into an if statement and other approaches but nothing is working. I'm trying to allow the user to input the radius in case 1 and then I wanted to use that value in the rest of the cases but it won't work at all. This could be me making a very stupid mistake but any help is appreciated, and sorry if I've done this post wrong this was my last resort because I've been stuck for hours.

Comment: Just FY, "I'm getting errors" doesn't help us much.  If you actually copy and paste the full error into your question, it will help you get answers much faster.  Also, try just reading the error.  *"variable `radius` might not have been initialized"* Pretty tells you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pasted your code into Eclipse.
The only thing that was not working was that 
the following variables needed to be initialized:

```
double area, perimeter, radius = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you! That's all I needed, you're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error :

```
error: variable radius might not have been initialized
case '2': System.out.println("The radius is " + radius);
```

Then this is because you are printing the radius value before initializing it, so you need to give a default value before printing it.

Comment: I tried initiazing it before but I did it inside the do while loop which meant that it wasn't working which made me think that wasn't where I was going wrong. Its running fine though now since I initialised it in the main, thank you for your help.